# Mean and median line in seaborn histplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Seaborn v0.11.0 just came out with the very useful histplot function. One thing I am trying to figure out is how best to display the mean and/or median on the plot. There seems to be no option for this in the function itself, as far as I could see in the documentation.

Does anyone know how adding a line for mean and/or median could be easily achieved?

Comment: Your question is much too broad. An answer depends on personal taste, the dimensionality and amount of data, what aspects you want to highlight, and much more. For a 1D histogram you might just draw `axvline(np.mean(x))`. Or one of the hundredths of other ways on this forum means and medians are drawn for histograms and kdeplots. Just do a search; other people can't decide for you, especially with so little context.